# Brew: Consider setting your PATH so that /usr/local/bin occurs before /usr/bin

Tags: path, export, homebrew, profile

I know this must be a tedious question to ask again. However, I am only bringing this up again as even when I run the oneliner command in terminal and *restart* my terminal it doesn't change anything. Running brew doctor again after restarting will throw the same warning. This is weird as I did the same thing to another machine and worked as a charm.

Thanks
K.

Comment: I still get the warning even though my `usr/local/bin` is before `usr/bin`.

Answer (score 3):

Open your terminal and type this code:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

then quit and restart your terminal and type this:

```
brew doctor
```